# How to setup a content repository in Linux?

Tags: ftp, cdn, content-management

I want to setup a server that'll host documents and image files which can be accessed efficiently from other application servers and databases on the same enterprise data center. What are the some of the options available in Linux?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend an NFS server with a basic file tree management, for good access performance and simple access control.

Have a look on http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/nfs